# Get row data for non-matching column values

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I want to read the file (1600 rows) and get rows only the columns have different values (sno1, sno2, sno3 & sno4-should be not be equal value) and it should be above
50%.The example of output given below

**input.txt (tab-delimited)**

```
id sno1 sno2 sno3 sno4
R1 98.4 88.8 98.4 67.6
R2 100  100  100  100
R3 33.4 23.5 98.8 45.5
R4 53.5 78.7 88.8 67.5
R5 0    0    0    0
R6 88.8 98.8 67.6 100
```

**ouput.txt**

```
R4 53.5 78.7 88.8 67.5
R6 88.8 98.8 67.6 100
```

Here in R4 & R6 rows- all column values have not equal to each other and all are above 50%. Any help in awk/sed/perl is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perl-oneliner:

```
perl -nae 'undef %saw ; next if $. == 1; shift @F; next if grep { $_ < 50 or $saw{$_}++ } @F;  print ' input.txt
```

This basically translates to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

while (<>) {
  my @F = split(' ');  # split the current line
  my %seen;
  next if $. == 1;  # skip the heading
  shift @F;  # ignore first element

  next if grep { $_ < 50 or $seen{$_}++ } @F;  # ignore lines with
                                               # duplicate entries and
                                               # entries less than 50
  print;  # print current line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1d;/\S\+ \(\S\+\) .* \1/d;/\S\+ \S\+ \(\S\+\) .* \1/d;/\S\+ \S\+ \S\+ \(\S\+\) .* \1/d;/\S\+\( \(100\|[56789][0-9]\..\)\)\{4\}/!d' file
```

Comment: wow impressive, care to explain?

Answer (score -1):

We can compare each field with other fields in the row for nonequality and can also compare each field is greater than 50 value

```
awk '($2!=$3) &&($2!=$4) && ($2!=$5) && ($3!=$4) &&($3!=$5) &&($4!=$5) && ($2>50) && ($3>50) && ($4>50) && ($5>50) {print $0}' input.txt
```

PS: I assumed the number of columns are fixed.

Comment: This answer would be improved with some explanation of what your code block does and how.